# YouTube.Channels.list returns empty set only when called from apps.script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-api

I try to call from Apps-script to YT.channel.list API and get an empty result set.

```
var ids = ["UC02vWUR9BkzNhXmW_XO1Imw"];

    var draft = YouTube.Channels.list('id, snippet, statistics', {
      id: ids
    });
```

[image]

Even though I get a non-empty result on the API explorer (same channelId).

```
gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
      "part": [
        "snippet"
      ],
      "id": [
        "UC02vWUR9BkzNhXmW_XO1Imw",
        "UC02vWUR9BkzNhXmW_XO1Imw"
      ]
    })
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
```

What can it be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to map the ids array to a string

```
 ids.join()
```